# Creating a setup.py

Tags: python, packaging, setup.py

I have been working on a simple GUI tool for PIP and have a working prototype. I'm facing issues with creating a setup for it. The program is intended for Debian users (for now) and hence it'd like that after the installation a 'pip-gui' command from the terminal starts it for the user.

The link for the repository with the code is:
https://github.com/ayushpriya10/PIP-GUI

My attempt at making a setup can be found at:
https://github.com/GDGVIT/pip-gui

(The setup I created worked but then it didn't when I tampered a bit with it and hence I would prefer to make a fresh one instead of editing the existing one. I would like to make the necessary changes for the new setup on my personal repository and hence please let me know if I should make any changes to the structure of the repository.)

The code that I have currently is:

```
 import os
 import re
 import codecs
 from setuptools import setup, find_packages

 here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))


def find_version(*file_paths):
    try:
        f = codecs.open(os.path.join(here, *file_paths), "r", "latin1")
        version_file = f.read()
        f.close()
    except:
        raise RuntimeError("Unable to find version string.")

    version_match = re.search(r"^__version__ = ['\"]([^'\"]*)['\"]",
                          version_file, re.M)
    if version_match:
        return version_match.group(1)
    raise RuntimeError("Unable to find version string.")


try:
    f = codecs.open("README.rst", encoding="utf-8")
    long_description = f.read()
    f.close()
except:
    long_description = ""

setup(
    name="pip-gui",
    version=find_version("pip_gui/mainGUI.py"),
    description="",
    url="https://github.com/GDGVIT/pip-gui",
    author="GDGVIT",
    packages=find_packages(include=[
        "pip_gui",
        "pip_gui.*"
    ]),
    include_package_data=True,
    # py_modules=["pip_gui.mainGUI"],
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            "pip-gui=pip_gui.mainGUI:main"
        ] 
    },
    classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: 4 - Beta",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License",
        "Environment :: X11 Applications :: Qt",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 2",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 2 :: Only",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: CPython"
    ],
    install_requires=[
    "beautifulsoup4>=4.5, <4.5.4"
    ]
)
```

The installation via 'pip install pip-gui' runs without any errors but the command 'pip-gui' in terminal shows the error 'command not found'.

Some changes that I want to make is changing the author to 'Ayush Priya ' and the URL pointing to my personal repository.

Comment: Post code. Don't make us follow links.

Comment: There are several files that are linked. How exactly do I post them here? As I said, I'm new here.. :)

Comment: Reduce the problem to a minimal example and post the code from that.

Comment: Perhaps some excerpts that are causing the problems?

Comment: There are some cookiecutter templates to help create a python package - you might want to check out https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter-pypackage (and it suggests alternatives too if it doesn't do exactly what you want)

Comment: I'll surely check them out once. :)

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  After installing inside a virtualenv, the `pip-gui` command is found, though it fails with `ImportError: No module named PyQt4`.  If you're installing your package system-wide (generally not recommended), then `pip-gui` should have been created in `/usr/local/bin`; is that directory in your `PATH`?

Comment: @jwodder I'm sorry. I forgot to mention that to use this one needs PyQt4 installed. for the rest of what you said, I don't exactly my setup does right now. I used what i could find from the web and tried making it work. I've got zero experience in packaging.

Answer (score 0):

If a hyphen is appended to the package name (with no intervening space), the identified package will be removed if it is installed. This is just console formatting, so try removing the hyphen from pip-gui (make it pipgui).

Once that is done, if the program is in the directory your console is in, you should be able to just type the package name. Alternatively, use the full path - ie /path/to/program or cd to the directory and run ./program_name